# Yesterday, Site on Page1, Today, Site Gone

Tags: seo

I understand the whole work of SEO etc. However my site has been steadily holding page 2 for months. I had time to add contextual links, and site went direct to page 1 yesterday. This site and URL now can't be found at all. I should think if anything it would get back to page 2.

Thanks a lot for adding thoughts?

Thanks a lot,

Byron

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned anything important to answer your question.

Anyway, assuming that you are searching in Google for your website, I have one suggestion.

Do check your site health in webmaster tools. And also read the [basic seo optimization guides](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf). Enhance the webpages with HTML5 technologies and Schema. Have patience.

Comment: I have. In fact went so well the site was on Page 1. Then disappeared. Plus a page of that site staid but has eventually vanished just now. Is there anyway I can contact Google?

Comment: Check Google Webmasters for the website. They inform in webmaster tools if they penalized for anything.Also check robots.txt. If it is OK, check if the website having good authority and back links. Resubmit the pages & sitemap to Google. If nothing works take some professional help or ask at Google Webmaster Forums.

Comment: I did all that there seemed there was a problem with robots.txt and I added one but no errors to report. I didn't put sitemaps before and it worked plus Google webmaster console does not point any problems with the sitemaps not being there.

Comment: the strange thing is this site is searchable on mobile device only I submitted for crawl in all devices